# Clojure `case` doesn't differentiate different symbols

Tags: clojure, case

This code works:

```
(case '-
    + :plus
    - :minus
    :unknown)
==> :minus
```

This too:

```
(case '-
    + :plus
    '- :minus
    * :times
    :unknown)
==> :minus
```

This doesn't:

```
(case '-
    '+ :plus
    '- :minus
    * :times
    :unknown)
==> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate case test constant: quote
```

Googling for this error leads to [log file here](http://clojure-log.n01se.net/date/2011-05-31.html). However, the guy just said it worked with quotes removed.

It looks like the case statement treats different symbols as the same value. Why is this so?

TIA.

Comment: There's a typo in the question at the moment (15 hours after original question, 10 hours after an edit): The second and third examples are identical.  Based on answers below and my own experiments, it sounds as if there should be a quote symbol before "+" in the third example.  However I don't want to try to edit it since I'm not sure.  (I'm also not sure whether I have the power to edit this question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `case` documentation:

```
Each clause can take the form of either:

test-constant result-expr

(test-constant1 ... test-constantN)  result-expr
```

`'-` expands to `(quote -)`.

Therefore, the clauses in the case with quotes expand to:

```
(quote -) :minus
(quote +) :plus
```

As you can see, the symbol "quote" appears as an actual test constant, and when you quote both + and -, it appears twice.

Evaluating the `case` on the actual symbol `quote` might clarify things:

```
user=> (case 'quote '+ :plus - :minus :unknown)
:plus
user=> (case 'foo (foo +) :plus - :minus :unknown)
:plus
```

Comment: The `case` documentation does even directly address this: "The test-constants are not evaluated. They must be compile-time literals, and need not be quoted."

Comment: Thanks. I should have inspected the docs more carefully. I came from c and python, so I thought it in the c switch statement way. The clojure way is more powerful.

Comment: To achieve what you want, you should use `(condp = +, + :plus, - :minus)`